# How can I access the current user from within an AccessDeniedHandler in symfony 3.4?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

Using symfony 3.4 I want to use an AccessDeniedHandler as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/access_denied_handler.html). How can I access the current user from within that AccessDeniedHandler?

Comment: I think you would add to a/the constructor a reference to the `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security` service, which then exposes `$security->getUser()`.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony provide a service that allow you to retrieve the logged in user (if any)

Just adapt your class constructor with the `TokenStorageInterface`

```
public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}
```

You can access to the user like follow

```
if (null === $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
    // No authentication token in the security context
}

$user = $token->getUser();

if (is_string($user)) {
    // getUser can return a string with "anon." if the firewall allow anonymous user
} elseif ($user instanceof UserInterface) {
    // You got your user :)
}
```

Comment: The `TokenStorage` of course is the 2/3 option. Do you know how the (since 3.4) `Security` service obviates the need to get the `TokenStorage` service? I'll certainly remember the latter easier... LOL.

Comment: `Security` service use the container directly. It's a bad practice (yes I know this class come from Symfony codebase) for performance and readability reasons. Personally I implement the same logic, with needed classes injected in the constructor. No use of container directly in my code :)

Comment: You're referring to things like [`return $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')`](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/3d792c499cfd3638c97b8b1bd350cbf6e19bc9ad/Security.php#L63)?

Comment: Yes, it's not a big deal, but it's better with direct injection :) No fetching from container at runtime

Comment: I see Ryan Weaver worked on it; I suspect lowering the bar of entry is the benefit. Never been a big fan of calling it `TokenStorage`, which seems too generic for what it provides.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the current user using the core security component.

On your AccessDeniedHandler class:

```html
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

protected $security;

public function __construct(Security $security)
{
    $this->security = $security;  
}

public function doSomething()
{
    /** @var \App\Entity\User $user */
    $user = $this->security->getUser();
}
```